# How has dropzonejs.com 100% height on their <header> tag?

Tags: html, css

I can't see their header set to 100%.

Also it works without Javascript.

I noticed some inline style in their  tag with seems to updated, whenever I resize their window:

**header inline style**

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 1;
```

Yet I don't know how they are doing it and I am curious, can someone provide the answer for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewport units:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths

100vh (always 100% of the viewport height)

100vw (always 100% of the viewport width)

Comment: I worked with viewpoint units in other designs, yet I couldn't find viewport units in their source, are you sure about this?

Comment: Yes. Line 267 of style.css `@media (min-width: 700px) { body > header { height: 100vh; margin-bottom: 0; }`

Comment: Now that you are saying it, I see it too. Don't know why I didn't saw it before, even though it was in plain sight. Thank you Adam. Edit: When the counter runs down, I'll accept your answer.